# how to change route with rails 4.2,1/ruby 2.2.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to change the route for an Rails app that I'm building. I'm using c9.io's IDE.

The route folder has the following code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home/index'
end
```

When I change it to:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'home#index'
end
```

So that I can route the index page to the home page it produces an error.

Do I need to change the code in my controller or view files?

Comment: I'm trying to root the homepage of my Rails app to the index page. But it doesn't root properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do this.  You want to root the `"/"` page to the home controller index action?

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

Comment: With rails 4.2 you can just say     root "home#index"

Comment: Yes. Thanks for your help!